# How do I fix my React Native failing Android build in Gradle? com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have tried generating a signed APK according to the instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

When running `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I get a build error as seen below. My app uses Google Firebase for authentication and tipsi-stripe as one of its main libraries. It is a detached Expo build.

I have tried adding additional dependencies, including Firebase core in `app/build.gradle`

The error in the terminal.

```
❯ ./gradlew assembleRelease
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

{..}
> Task :tipsi-stripe:compileReleaseRenderscript FAILED
> Task :app:checkDevKernelReleaseClasspath FAILED
> Task :react-native-firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':tipsi-stripe:compileReleaseRenderscript' property 'importDirs' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.2.0,16.2.0]], but resolves to 17.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.


==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:checkDevKernelReleaseClasspath' property 'compileClasspath' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.2.0,16.2.0]], but resolves to 17.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.


==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':react-native-firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript' property 'importDirs' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.2.0,16.2.0]], but resolves to 17.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.


==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 18s
38 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 35 up-to-date
```

- My `app/build.gradle`: https://gist.github.com/christopheragnus/35c13d31976c889268b663cbf1654ead
- My root `/build.gradle`: https://gist.github.com/christopheragnus/e6f506d6882ad37ce7656140a240f5bf

EDIT:

I tried changing `/build.gradle` to use version 16.2.0,

```
resolutionStrategy {
         ...
          force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0'
        }
```

This resulted in a different but same type of error:

```
> Task :tipsi-stripe:compileReleaseRenderscript FAILED
> Task :app:checkDevKernelReleaseClasspath FAILED
> Task :react-native-firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript FAILED

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':tipsi-stripe:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:11.8.0.
...
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:11.8.0.
...
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:11.8.0.
```